# What's the correct way to use ObjectResult with input parameters to StoredProcedure in Entity Framework? (Output mapped to Complex Type Property)

Tags: c#, wpf, stored-procedures, entity-framework-4.1, complextype

I have several listboxes which have a SelectedItem property I intend to use as input parameters to execute my stored procedure in Entity Framework.

I now realize my only hope for easily returning entity objects as the result of my Stored Procedure is to map the Stored Procedure (or Function Import) to a complex type which matches the output. (Used Julie Lerman's post [here](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/a-big-step-for-stored-procedures-in-ef4/) to make this decision.)

However, I need help using ObjectResult with EntityFramework to capture my listbox SelectedItem properties and feed them to the Stored Procedure (and thus output my complex type entities). Is anyone familiar with this process?

ANY help would be appreciated (guesses included). Please let me know if I can be more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access it as a function call, and the order of the parameters is determined by EF:

```
using (var db = new YourEntityContext())
{
    var result = db.YourFunctionImportName(
        Convert.ToInt32(ddlWhatever1.SelectedValue),
        Convert.ToInt32(ddlWhatever2.SelectedValue));

    //Int32 used as an example, use whatever type your function import is expecting.
    //Do whatever with result.
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Still a little confused regarding how I dump contents of result (which is table) to my complex type entity. Could you provide a little more detail? I'm a beginner here.

Comment: EF should take care of all of that for you - if the return type on the SQL side is `table`, in the EF designer you should be able to map columns to properties in the complex type and then specify that the function returns an `IEnumerable` of the complex type.

Comment: Thank you for your response--I'm still a bit unclear how result gets fed to my entity.

Comment: When debugging the equivalent of the sample code in the answer, what type is result? It should be `IEnumerable<T>` of your "entity" or user defined complex type.

Comment: my method looks like:

private IEnumerable <ReturnPnsPerAtts_result> GetPnsPerAttsQuery(MyEntities myEntities){ var pnsPerAttsQuery = myEntities.ResturnPnsPerAtts(Convert.ToInt32(shapeListBox.SelectedValue),....,Convert.ToInt32(attribute12ListBox.SelectedValue));
return pnsPerAttsQuery;

which I call with:
IEnumerable<ReturnPnsPerAtts_Result> pnsPerAttsQuery = this.GetReturnPnsPerAttsQuery(myEntities);

Yet my view is empty.