# How to correctly invoke a function that maps a SProc to ObservableCollection  in Entity Framework where Objects are of Complex Type

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-4, complextype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the correct way to use ObjectResult with input parameters to StoredProcedure in Entity Framework? (Output mapped to Complex Type Property)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836345/whats-the-correct-way-to-use-objectresult-with-input-parameters-to-storedproced)

I've already asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11836345/1076406), but I can't seem to figure it out so I'm asking again.

I mapped a function in my Entity Model to a complex type called ReturnPnsPerAtts_Result which has scalar properties: pn_ID, conn_pn, and part_class.

That's done correctly.

The SQL SELECT Stored Procedure is called ReturnPnsPerAtts, which takes in about 12 parameters (which are all "attribute" properties from entity queries I've grabbed from the SelectedValue property of a bunch of listboxes in my view.

Now, I realize that I can return the result of my stored procedure as an ObjectResult of Complex Type. I am using WPF and C#--how exactly to I create a method to feed my ObjectResults to a DataContext??

Thanks--any help is greatly appreciated.

::EDIT:: What I've been trying:

My code now looks EXACTLY like this:

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
          CollectionViewSource returnPnsPerAtts_ResultViewSource = ((CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("returnPnsPerAtts_ResultViewSource");

          returnPnsPerAtts_ResultViewSource.Source = this.selectedPnsCollection;
     }

     private ObservableCollection<ReturnPnsPerAtts_Result> selectedPnsCollection = new ObservableCollection<ReturnPnsPerAtts_Result>();

     private void connShapeLBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
     {
          ConnCompAttsView selectedConnShape = this.connShapeLBox.SelectedValue as ConnCompAttsView;
           if (connShapeLBox.SelectedValue != null)
           {
                 selectedPnsCollection.Clear();
                 foreach (ReturnPnsPerAtts_Result result in 
                      this.myEntities.ReturnPnsPerAttsFN(selectedConnShape.PK_att_val_id, null, null, null, null, null));
                      {
                          selectedPnsCollection.Add(result);
                      }
              }
       }
      }
```

However, I'm getting an inner exception that states

```
 "{"Procedure or function 'ReturnPnsPerAtts' expects parameter '@@connShape', which was not supplied."}"
```

But it was supplied...or so I thought...and as an int, which is what my stored procedure expects.

Comment: _feed my ObjectResults to a DataContext_ What do you mean? You're supposed to _receive_ ObjectResults from your context by invoking the function that maps to the stored procedure and feeding it the required arguments.

Comment: @GertArnold I apologize for the confusion--I'm a beginner and am trying to figure out how it all works. What I want to do now is create an ObservableCollection to wrap (receive?) my complexType objects. I've been following the article: 

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsdata/archive/2010/06/18/wpf-edm-binding-to-stored-procedures.aspx 

but I'm not sure how to define/call the function that binds the results of my stored procedure to my observable collection. Please feel free to correct my phrasing as it helps me quite a bit.